# Loading Same Gallery Image Into Two Different Activity Fragments Android Picasso

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-recyclerview, picasso

Currently I have a Main Activity which has a Fragment loaded into it with a RecyclerView. In the RecyclerView adapter I use Picasso to load in images from the user's gallery based on a stored URI string I have like so:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(imageUri)
    .resize(400, 400)
    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
```

When the user clicks on one of these items in the RecyclerView I go to a new Activity and inside its own Fragment onCreateView I load the same image again but size it slightly larger (as the ImageView I'm loading it into is larger size)

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
    .load(imageUri)
    .resize(600, 600)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(imageView);
```

My question is...Assuming these images can be quite large...

Is there a better way to load in this image once at say 600px X 600px back when the RecyclerView first needs them, and then reuse the bitmap data in the subsequent Activities and Fragments which need it without reloading again?

I'm open to using a different image loader like Volley if that's better.

Any help would be appreciated.

Marco

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) it has almost the same api. Instead of Picasso glide has own cache implementation, when Picasso just use http cache and it's hard to control. In glide you need to specify [diskCacheStrategy.ALL](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/DrawableRequestBuilder.html#diskCacheStrategy(com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy)) to make glide cache all you want. Here is [cache wiki](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation)

Comment: Thanks Sone. I'll take a look into Glide to see if it suits my needs.

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue of loading images again in a new context.

Comment: @SouravChandra couldn't be true, works for me perfectly, looks like you are doing something wrong. Could you provide an example of your code?

Comment: I'm tried to use Glide because of lots of great references to it, but the images are not loaded in some devices, e.g. on *Samsumg Galaxy Nexus s7 Edge*, the image remains "blank":

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/738

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/130
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/911

Comment: @RichardSilveira All libraries has bugs, if you could reproduce it - lust fix it and send PR;)